# Interesting SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this data in my table:

```
onum    amt         odate                       cnum    snum

3001    18,69       1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     2008    1007
3002    1900,10     1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     2007    1004
3003    767,19      1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     2001    1001
3005    5160,45     1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     2003    1002
3006    1098,16     1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     2008    1007
3007    75,75       1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     2004    1002
3008    4723,00     1990-05-10 00:00:00.000     2006    1001
3009    1713,23     1990-04-10 00:00:00.000     2002    1003
3010    1309,95     1990-06-10 00:00:00.000     2004    1002
3011    9891,88     1990-06-10 00:00:00.000     2006    1001
```

I need get this result:

```
amt         odate                       snum

5160,45     1990-03-10 00:00:00.000     1002
4723,00     1990-05-10 00:00:00.000     1001
9891,88     1990-06-10 00:00:00.000     1001
```

that is I select the max `amt` on the each day `odate`, but with displaying of seller `snum`

if I write this:

```
 SELECT MAX(amt), odate, snum 
 FROM [Understanding].[dbo].[Orders] 
 GROUP BY odate, snum
```

the output is wrong because it displays the groups by days and sellers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select amt,
         odate,
         snum,
         row_number() over(partition by odate order by amt desc) as rn
  from Orders
)
select amt,
       odate,
       snum
from C
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I will never get used to the fact that SQL Server requires a semicolon at the beginning of a statement... ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Well, it's actually the last character of the statement before. The `merge` statement requires that it ends with a semicolon. `with` requires that the previous statement is terminated by a semicolon. If SQL Server required that every statement is to be terminated by semicolon it would be much more consistent. Perhaps it will in a future version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `WITH` can be used in various contexts in SQL Server. When it introduces a (list of) CTE(s), it must be at the beginning of a statement, in other cases it is supposed to be somewhere else but *not* at the beginning. The semicolon merely removes ambiguity as to the meaning of `WITH`. You don't have to put a semicolon when there are no statements before `WITH` (in the context of CTE definition).

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,b.snum
from
(
select MAX(amt) as amt
      ,odate 
from Orders
group by odate
)A INNER JOIN Orders B
ON A.amt = b.amt
order by a.odate
```